# How to fix Turkish character encoding issue in XAMPP MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Mysql Turkish Characters problem

Im using xampp mysql server for server.
But im trying to use it from the terminal/cmd.
When i query smth with turkish letters like "oğuz" , it returns "?" instead of "ğ" letter ex:"o?uz"

"xampp mysql cSet options"
`default-character-set=utf8mb4`
`character-set-server=utf8mb4`
`collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci`

Are these c-sets wrong?

update:
I did try `utf8mb4_turkish_ci` and `utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci`
Hex returned empty

Solution : Reinstalled the xampp (Some things was broken maybe) and it worked

Comment: See "question marks" (not "black diamond") in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  And see the `SELECT HEX(col)` top for debugging.  Also, you may prefer Collation `utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci` or `utf8mb4_turkish_ci` .  `utf8mb4_general_ci` is quite lame.

Comment: Thanks for help but it returns "-" now , like "o-uz" :(

Comment: Please update your question with new information rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: What steps did you take to get to `"-"`?

Comment: It's not `-` (U+002D,  *Hyphen-Minus*) but  `­` (U+00AD,  *Soft Hyphen*) by the following [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"oğuz".encode( 'cp1254').decode( 'cp857')` returns `'o\xaduz'` (some font renders *Soft Hyphen* as _minus_). Windows? Change code page `chcp 1254`, see https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html (The same example: `print( "oğuz".encode( 'cp1254').decode( 'cp857'))` -> `o­uz`).

Comment: aight guys Thanks y'all for the answers. i just reinstalled the xampp and it worked.i dunno why but if it is working dont touch it u know :>